# Legal script that scrapes and indexes?

Tags: php

I want to create a website that scrapes certain websites (specified by me) to collect data and pricing and then offer that data as search results on my own site. So basically like a search engine, but for specific sites, indexed in a specific way. I can write this myself, but would like to know:

1. Is it legal? Can I grab for example, all the items off ebay, put it in a search engine and allow users to search ebay using my site?
2. What if I make money off this?
3. Are there any popular PHP scripts that already do this?

The legal aspect has been covered. I found a way around this (well, I got permission from the persons creating the content)... so the only real question is: what can I use to crawl the content, especially keeping in mind, each site will have diffrent rules that I will have to set up? It must also be clever enough to not spider the same content twice?

Comment: Just answering 1) and 2). You're definitely going to run into content licensing. I batted around an idea of making a news aggregation portal that people could sign up for and select their favorite topics and get it all aggregated. I approached a few outlets for permission to scrape and such. They wanted to charge me like $1,000 per article.

I can only imagine re-posting their content for commercial purposes would been even more problematic with them.

Comment: @Foxtrot, some jurisdictions may differentiate between copyrightable content (such as news articles) and non-copyrightable facts (such as prices advertised on publicly accessible sites). That's why techos should not be giving legal advice :-)

Answer (score 4):

> Is it legal?

Yes. And no. Probably.

There isn't one set of laws covering the entire planet, and SO isn't really for legal advice, you need to find a lawyer in your jurisdiction.

My own thoughts are that you would probably be okay in most jurisdictions as long as you use only the *information.* So, no eBay logos, no representations that you may be associated with them and so on.

But I am not a lawyer (though I deal a lot with the US sub-species as part of my work), certainly not *your* lawyer, and this advice (which *isn't* legal advice) is worth every cent you paid for it, which is *ZERO!*

> What if I make money of this?

Good for you :-) Make mega-bucks. But see above point.

> Are there any popular PHP scripts that already do this?

That's the bit I can't answer. My experience with PHP ranges somewhere between zero and nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The legality is a bit shady in this area. You should look for the presence of a robots.txt ( http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html ) file to first determine if the website welcomes web spiders.

Also, there is a very good PHP search script called sphider ( http://www.sphider.eu/ ), you should have a look at.

EDIT:

I can't see many websites having an issue with you taking snippets of their website and then linking users onto the webpage which the content came from. However, if you plan on just taking all their content and displaying it on your own website in order to make profit, I can only assume many web sites would have an issue as they are the ones who should be profiting off the content.

Comment: It will definitely be for linking back to the original content, and never to pretend its my own content.

Answer (score 0):

1) Is it legal? Can I grab for example, all the items off ebay, put it in a search engine and allow users to search ebay using my site?

This is technically feasible. You can build a PHP script that does this quite easily. I would say that it is borderline illegal however, because by scraping content from somebody elses site you will be using their intellectual property, their data without permission.

2) What if I make money off this?

Then the original owners of the data are very likely to come after you, issue a cease and desist notice then sue you. An organization as large as ebay could do this without blinking.

3) Are there any popular PHP scripts that already do this?

Because of the questionable legal nature of your question, I highly doubt there are any scripts that already do this.

---

The correct technique of getting data from ebay and other large data providers is by using APIs, or application programming interfaces. These are special protocols, languages, designed for programs to communicate with each other. This has the benifit of being significantly more efficient than page-scraping, while also being a known legal way to get data from a provider.

More information about the ebay specific API can be found here; http://developer.ebay.com/common/api/